# IP address in specific city

Tags: exit-relays

Do I have the ability to choose an exit IP Address at city-level? I need my IP address to show as Phoenix, Arizona. How do I chose that location for an IP Address?

Comment: You can combine Tor to provide anonymity then use a proxy to make the collection look like from wherever you'd like. Please refer to : http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/4679/1785

Comment: related http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer your question, I want to point out that if you just need to appear to be in Phoenix, and aren't concerned with anonymity, it would be much easier to use a Phoenix Az proxy.

To do this with Tor isn't really what Tor was designed for, but you should have good luck by choosing what countries you want your exit node to use (or not use.) From there you will probably have to test until find one that exists inside Phoenix, and add that fingerprint to your preferred exit node list. Or if you know the ip address range you're looking for (my Phoenix Az IP starts with 68.106.x.x) you can add it instead of a country code or fingerprint.

[Choose Entry/Exit](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit)

The following options can be added to your config file "torrc" or specified on the command line:

You can list preferred nodes to use for the last hop in the circuit, if possible by setting the ExitNodes:

```
ExitNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint
```

Instead of `$fingerprint` you can also specify a 2 letter ISO3166 country code in curly braces (for example `{de}`), or an ip address pattern (for example 255.254.0.0/8), or a node nickname. Make sure there are no spaces between the commas and the list items.

It seems like people are having better luck excluding countries instead of using them with the above command:

```
ExcludeNodes {be},{pl},{ca},{za},{vn},{uz},{ua},{tw},{tr},{th},{sk}, 
    {sg},{se},{sd},{sa},{ru},{ro},{pt},{ph},{pa},{nz},{np},{no},{my},{mx}, 
    {md},{lv},{lu},{kr},{jp},{it},{ir},{il},{ie},{id},{hr},{hk},{gr},{gi}, 
    {gb},{fi},{es},{ee},{dk},{cz},{cy},{cr},{co},{cn},{cl},{ci},{ch},{by}, 
    {br},{bg},{au},{at},{ar},{aq},{ao},{ae},{nl},{de},{fr}
```

Tor doesn't recomend selecting your entry/exit nodes, stating:

> We recommend you do not use these — they are intended for testing and
>   may disappear in future versions. You get the best security that Tor
>   can provide when you leave the route selection to Tor; overriding the
>   entry / exit nodes can mess up your anonymity in ways we don't
>   understand.

Answer (score 2):

Tor uses the GeoIP database from Maxmind. This resolves domains on a country level. So by setting `ExitNode` you can choose a specific country (`us`, `ca`, `ar` etc.), but inside Tor there is no possibility to select relays on a per-city-basis.

You could use another GeoIP database and check if there is a relay sitting in Phoenix. If you find one or more you could use the `ExitNode` together with the fingerprint of that node(s).

However as Garrett Fogerlie pointed out it is not Tor's main purpose to do such things. You might be better off by looking for a general open proxy in Phoenix if you just need an outgoing IP address there. Furthermore also a Phoenix based VPN service might help here.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Browser folder, open the TorBrowser folder, open the data folder, open the Tor folder, open the `torrc` file, and add `ExitNodes {US}` (if you want a us proxy on tor) to the top of the second section as so:

This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
The old torrc file was renamed to `torrc.orig.1` or similar, and Tor will ignore it

```
ExitNodes {US}
DataDirectory C:\Users\******\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\******\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
```

save the file and launch tor, there u go.

Answer (score 0):

In Tor Browser Bundle, you can specify the country of the ExitNodes by editing the file "torrc-defaults".

Details:
http://miscool.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-get-fake-ip-address-of-specific-country.html

see also:
http://malwaretips.com/threads/how-to-change-ip-address-on-tor-browser-into-specific-country.27653/

But not sure how to do that for a specific city.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you get to choose an IP address. The exit node which ends up returning the IP address is random after your connection request has hopped through 3 random relays after leaving your computer.

Comment: You can configure what your exit node is in the config file. This can be a particular exit/IP, an IP range, or even a geo-code (so you can get an exit in a particular country or region).