# Any way to use Flash with Tor (to ONLY view country-blocked video streams)?

Tags: configuration, windows, censorship, plugin, network-configuration

How can I configure Tor, with the Flash player, for **ONLY** accessing region-banned videos?

Comment: you could try opting in for the the youtube html5 video player at https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=NL&hl. You might have to enable cookies and javascript for this to work. If this fails you could try downloading the video from a yotube proxy website.

Comment: Where are these proxies? Any example?

Comment: @Karolinger google it

Comment: The proxy <a href="http://www.hola.org">hola.org</a> does a good job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Stealthy](http://www.stealthy.co/), a [plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stealthy/). If you encounter a blocked page, Stealthy switches to an open proxy in another country and tries downloading it through this proxy. However those are *not* Tor proxies, but simple open proxies.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You first need to get a fake IP for the specific region, then you need to activate the Flash plugin, which by default is disabled in the Tor Browser.
Check the answer of
[IP address in specific city](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/ip-address-in-specific-city/4591#4591) for IP address and the answer of
[Why can't Tor Browser use Adobe Flash Player?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/why-cant-tor-browser-use-adobe-flash-player/4592#4592) for Flash plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Stealthy is good. The other option is to use psiphon to appear to be in a different country. Also its dependent on whether the web server or the CDN/streaming server is doing the checks. I'm no expert at web development, but I imagine the html-serving servers are doing the country checks, in which case using flash should theoretically work but it will also expose your real ip address, for those who are concerned about that. Why can't someone make a gnash open source flash plugin that plays videos?!

Answer (score 1):

In the first answer you got the hint to use proxies to watch the videos. Beside Tor there are another way. You could use savefrom.net to watch and download the Videos. Beside: this would not use the limited traffic within the Tor-network.
Simply go on these website and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

While a lot of people are suggesting to use plugins and other such potentially risky solutions, you may want to try using a video player that supports flash. The `mpv` program, for example, can play flash videos embedded within `.swf` files (i.e. the same type in `.flv` files). While it doesn't support a SOCKS proxy out of the box, you can use `torsocks` with it to send traffic through Tor.

Comment: `.swf` is a Shockwave Flash file. It's literally an executable of flash bytecode. You might mean `.flv` which is a Flash Video? (Although they're normally just MP4 files...)