# Why can't Tor Browser use Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, flash

So some games I tried on Tor need Adobe Flash Player.

I've downloaded Adobe Flash Player three times now, and the game still can't be played.

Any help?

Comment: Even with flash working, Tor might not be fast enough to run a game. I have to ask why a game would need to be played over Tor.

Comment: downvoted because this answer not only doesn't answer the question, but is wrong. if it's a game that doesn't need to access the network that much, Tor Browser would be able to run the game fine (because Tor only makes network connections slow; everything that happens locally runs at normal speed). also, asking why someone wants to do something over Tor isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Following, please find a quote from Tor.

> The Tor Browser will block browser plugins such as Flash, RealPlayer,
>   Quicktime, and others: they can be manipulated into revealing your IP
>   address.

Using Adobe Flash is enough to break your anonymity. Thus, Tor does not allow Adobe Flash to be used accidently or inadvertently. However If you want to use Adobe Flash and you do not care to keep your anonymity secured, there is no good reason to use Tor, because one of the main purposes of Tor is to keep the user anonymous. You may use any free or paid VPN instead.

Answer (score 8):

Adobe Flash is very insecure and vulnerable. There are many ways people can expoit Flash to get your real identity, so using Flash in Tor is like having glass windows in tank.. You can get it working with Tor, but it is highly unrecommended to do so. Use a VPN instead.

Answer (score 4):

The Tor developers explain this on the [Tor Project website](https://www.torproject.org/). I am going to include the quotes at the end of this answer.

The Tor Browser is a browser designed for anonymous communication. To ensure the users' privacy, Tor's developers decided to block many browser plugins like Flash or Quicktime. These plugins were not developed with security in mind, and can leak information (e.g. IP) about the users. These plugins represent an unnecessary threat.

Flash has been criticized a lot recently, due to its security flaws. The Hacking Team 2015 data breach<sup>1</sup> revealed several 0day cross-platform Flash exploits. ([CVE-2015-0349](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-0349), [CVE-2015-5119](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-5119), [CVE-2015-5122](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2015-5122), [CVE-2015-5123](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-5123).) This shows how unreliable the Flash plugin is, and highlights the developers' decision.

Even if, as far as I know, you *can* run the Flash plugin in the Tor Browser, I would strongly advise against running it.

<sup><sup>1</sup> 400 GB of data leaked;

Hacking Team is an Italian company specialized in offensive intrusion and the development of surveillance tools, selling them to governments.</sup>

---

Explained in the Tor FAQ:

> **Why can't I view videos on some Flash-based sites?**
>
> Some sites require third party browser plugins such as Flash. Plugins
>   operate independently from Firefox and can perform activity on your
>   computer that ruins your anonymity. This includes but is not limited
>   to: completely disregarding proxy settings, querying your [local IP
>   address](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5162138&messageID=9618376), and [storing their own cookies](https://epic.org/privacy/cookies/flash.html). It is possible to use a LiveCD
>   solution such as or [The Amnesic Incognito Live System](https://tails.boum.org) that creates a
>   secure, transparent proxy to protect you from proxy bypass, however
>   issues with local IP address discovery and Flash cookies still remain.
>
> <sup>Source: [**Why can't I view videos on some Flash-based sites?** - Tor FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBFlash)</sup>
>   <sup>*Note: the first link is dead and redirects you to Oracle homepage.*</sup>

Repeated in the download page:

> **c. Don't enable or install browser plugins**
>
> The Tor Browser will block browser plugins such as Flash, RealPlayer,
>   Quicktime, and others: they can be manipulated into revealing your IP
>   address. Similarly, we do not recommend installing additional addons
>   or plugins into the Tor Browser, as these may bypass Tor or otherwise
>   harm your anonymity and privacy.
>
> <sup>Source: [**Want Tor to really work?** - Download Tor](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The lastest Tor Browser allows you to activate Flash Player although you should be aware that this is insecure. You need to install Flash Player for FireFox first at http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ . Then go to "about:addons" to activate it.

Ref: http://miscool.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-get-fake-ip-address-of-specific-country.html
(see the post's second part on how to activate Flash plugin manually.)