# How to use a country specific Exit node for IRC, but random exit node for anything else?

Tags: tails, configuration

While using Tails is it possible to use an exit node based in Norway which I want to use to connect to a Norwegian IRC server (the server blocks non-norwigian IPs).

But I want all other traffic go through random exit nodes.

To summarise... for IRC use 'this' exit node, but for everything else use any exit node.

Comment: If you just want an IP in Norway (not anonymity), a proxy is probably a better bet (and you can probably configure that in your IRC client).

Comment: related http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve the result you're looking for quite simply thanks to [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/).

It would be too hard to force Tor to use a specific exit node though.

Proxychains works by routing your traffic through multiple proxies that you can easily configure.

It supports Socks so you can choose Tor as your first proxy *(this is even the default configuration)*, then pick a Norwegian proxy (socks or http, as you wish) to make your connection look like it comes from Norway.

The great thing about proxychains is that you specify which application will use this chains of proxies, as such :

```
$ proxychains iceweasel 
$ proxychains <irc-client>
```

You can even start multiple sessions of your browser, one with the default Tails routing, and the other through additional proxie(s) after the Tor circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but according to my best understanding, this would get you close:

In your torrc,

- Use the `ExitNodes` directive to pick a node in {no} that *only* allows IRC exit.
- Set `StrictNodes` to 0 so that other connections will use different exits.

(I don't know how Tor behaves in this situation, but maybe once you have a circuit to another exit that *also* allows IRC, it gets used for IRC instead of building a new circuit to your preferred one. In that case, this doesn't work.)