# Setting the country of the tor ExitNodes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, exit-relays, geoip

I'm having some trouble in setting the country of the tor exit nodes. Following [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node?newreg=b443bfb9dcb647c9863a7567bf7e03f0) link, by adding the bellow entries to the ./Data/torrc

```
ExitNodes {ru}
StrictNodes 1
```

an exit node from the specified region should be used. However, geo locating the exit nodes shows that none are from Russia. Upon picking a new identity the exit node always remains in the EU or US. Why is that?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but I wanted to say that I tried those configuration commands with my copy of the Tor Browser Bundle and it seemed to work. Perhaps you put the commands in the wrong configuration file? Try putting nonsense into your config file and then running the command ``tor --verify-config''; if it doesn't complain then that means you're using the wrong config file

Comment: @user194 I have tried it in the latest version of tor(4.5) and it worked. It doesn't work in version 3.5.

Comment: if that answers your question, please update it to show this is closed

Comment: @ Lizbeth Done.

Comment: @sebi Actually it would be better if you posted it as an answer, and later accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to a more recent version of TOR(>= 4.5) allows for specific exit node selection. The issue may have been caused by high latency; in the previous versions of TOR circuits with a certain delay may have been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax in 2022 are for your sample, the follow:

ExitNodes {ru} StrictNodes 1

The follow should be more save. The additional {??} should protect you for Server whith unknown IP-country relation.

ExitNodes {ru}, {??} StrictNodes 1

Comment: The question wants to use a relay from {ru}, not exclude it.

Comment: @Steve, i fixed it now. THX