# How to set Tor for use in the UK and other countries

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, identity-change

I am using the latest version of the Tor Browser, but I am at a loss on how to configure it for a UK (and other countries, later on) IP address.

Obviously, I want to appear that I am in the UK to watch the BBC.

Things have changed with Tor and I would greatly appreciate some assistance. Thanks and cheers!

I would like instructions for 5.0.3 (2015) (based on Mozilla Firefox 38.3.0)!

A short procedure on how to do this would be wonderful.

This is not a duplicate. :)

Comment: I've flagged this as duplicate, but you basically want to look at the following FAQ entry: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/733/71

Comment: Also, if you just want to watch iPlayer you may be better with a VPN. Streaming video over Tor will be slow for you and affect the rest of the network's users too.