# I'm looking for torrc to add a minor edit, but can only find torrc.orig or torrc.default. Where can I go to edit?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, exit-relays

I'm trying to change the exit relay node of Tor to the UK, temporarily ([as advised here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node?newreg=b443bfb9dcb647c9863a7567bf7e03f0)). The advice is to add a bit of code in torrc.

Now, I can find only the files "old" torrc, torrc.orig (empty) and torrc.defaults on my machine, none of which seem to do the job - they are very small files and don´t contain much code. What am I missing? 
Note, I'm completely uneducated in this field and just trying to follow instructions posted on this forum, apologies for the naive question. Apologies and appreciations in advance.

Comment: Possibly look for a folder called TorBrowser-Data.

Answer (score 1):

For the Linux Tor Browser bundle, the file you are looking for is in

```
BUNDLE/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
```