# Strange anomaly using Facebook with Tor

Tags: exit-relays

I have been using Facebook with the Tor browser, with the exit node set always to be in a European country. Facebook has notified me that twice in the last 24 hours I have logged in from different African and Middle Eastern locations. I can't believe that someone in Dar es Salaam, and someone else in Saudi Arabia, have really logged into my account. So, what Tor anomaly is making Facebook think I am logging in from there?

P.S. I wanted to set Facebook as a tag for this question, but I don't yet have enough cudos here to create it. Facebook is a rather important website. Why doesn't it already exist as a tag on here? Can someone create it for me please! Thank you :-)

Comment: [GeoIP is bullshit](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception#geoip-is-bullshit) also [harmful](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/36013872/why-the-internet-is-blaming-one-us-farm-for-hundreds-of-scams-and-online-fraud).

Comment: I'm not sure there needs to be a facebook tag, this isn't facebook support.

Comment: Try the facebook hidden service https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/

Answer (score 1):

Canonizing ironize hit the nail on the head. IP mapping is inaccurate at best, and completely off the mark most of the time.

I was going to suggest using StrictNodes, but it would seem this only applies to excluded nodes: [Can I exit from a specific country or node?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node#comment6119_850)

Answer (score 0):

for access to faceboob, you may want to check into using some [free] vpn service for that locale.
i use country specific exitnodes only for sites that either dont have vpn service for that location or that particular vpn service was tagged and rejected by the site i access.  nevertheless, as @canonizingironize highlighted, my experience is the same = exitnodes are not guaranteed and are inaccurate.  to compensate for the inaccuracy, i use exitnodes in conjunction w/ something like geoiptool, mylocation.org etc. and access the resource only when i see my traffic is exiting in that location.

Answer (score -1):

It's OK - I'm using it myself like this, this stuff happens. Even if you're restricting `ExitNodes` - there're an IP-to-Country location inaccuracy that causes this kind of events.