# How to circumvent a ban from DVDFab?

Tags: relays

A specific IP in the Tor network gets me kicked off dvdfab.com forum. I see a pop up that says an administrator banned this address.

Can I set tor to not use it or can tor not use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I exit from a specific country or node?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node)

Comment: Kind of a duplicate, maybe? But you can use the inverse, `ExcludeExitNodes` instead of `ExitNodes`, to not use specific exit nodes. Note that it's a bad idea in general, see the post for reasons why.

Comment: If you can, please consider using a regular VPN service.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because the question is about exiting a specific country and the OP wants to exclude one or more relays.

Comment: The question does explicit state "country or node" but fair enough, maybe the answers don't address the second point as explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Tor in way that it doesn't use this specific IP address. Tor has a configuration option called `ExcludeExitNodes`:

> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes, and
>            address patterns of nodes to never use when picking an
>            exit node---that is, a node that delivers traffic for
>            you outside the Tor network. Note that any node listed
>            in ExcludeNodes is automatically considered to be part
>            of this list too. See the ExcludeNodes option for more
>            information on how to specify nodes. See also the
>            caveats on the "ExitNodes" option below.

So the best is to go to https://atlas.torproject.org/ and search for this IP address. Click on the entry and look for the fingerprint of the relay. Enter a line with `ExcludeExitNodes FINGERPRINT` into your torrc where `FINGERPRINT` is the value you found in the above page. When you restart Tor it won't use this exit address anymore.