# Setting a usa IP address TAILS/ TOR

Tags: security

I need to set TAILS/ TOR to an IP address that resides in the USA. I do not know how to do this. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think [this thread](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node) will answer your question. I used Tails only once, but opening a terminal (command prompt window) and typing something like `sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc`, should help you to add the proper lines (the ones in the other thread)...

Hope this help. Ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a lot of experience here.  And you have a number of ip addresses that tor connect to before you get to the internet.  I dont' know which one you need to be in the US.  The first or the exit.
But I can tell you that I use bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org/
and most of the good bridge connections seem to start in the US.  In otherwords, the bridge is a US ip address that then goes off to two more international addresses before exiting to the internet.  If that makes sense.
So you may want to try a bridge.