# Prevent Tor Browser from connecting to a node in a certain country?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays

I want to prevent Tor Browser from connecting to any nodes in a certain country. How do I do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I exit from a specific country or node?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node)

Answer (score 1):

Add to your torrc file:

ExcludeNodes {cc}

replacing cc by the country code you want excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in reading [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Tor#Rules_for_Tor_circuits). Avoiding certain Tor nodes is basically useless.