# Tor Browser does not use exit nodes from specified country on certain websites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

**I just realized that on certain websites the tor-browser ignores my exit node policy.**

I specify a certain country as exit node but on certain websites the circuit changes on its own and I receive exit nodes all around the world. With other websites it is working as intended.

One website where I have seen this behavior at https://www.4chan.org/ or [www.mixloud.com](http://www.mixloud.com) for example. But there are many others too, which I do not want to list.

1. **Is this behavior intended?**
2. **Is there any solution to this?**

```
cat torrc
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1, and Tor will ignore it

ClientOnionAuthDir /home/alex/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/onion-auth
DataDirectory /home/alex/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
ExitNodes {de}
GeoIPFile /home/alex/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /home/alex/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6
```