# CloudFlare versus Tor ExitNodes setting

Tags: circuit, cloudflare

This question [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/tor-browser-does-not-use-exit-nodes-from-specified-country-on-certain-websites) asked a similar thing. But I want to ask a more specific one.

We know that to force Tor browser to use exit nodes from certain country, we should edit file `torrc` with a line like this:

```
ExitNodes {xx} StrictNodes 1
```

where `xx` is the ISO country code.

This technique works fine for me when I visit most websites. However, for websites that have a CloudFlare check before loading, I notice that the Tor circuit changes to many countries while the CloudFlare is checking. The CloudFlare check I am seeing is to ask the user to tick the box "I am human". And during this, the exit node is not confined to the country set in `torrc`, but jumping all over the world.

An example of such website is `www.4chan.org`.

What exactly is CloudFlare doing? Is it forcing the traffic from Tor browser? What is this mechanism they are doing, if there is a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is "deanonymizing" - that's what Google, Amazon, Apple and many others are doing. To avoid this case you need to use a normal browser on a VM jail-routed through Tor via TransPort, so they can do whatever they want - but they will never be able to spot the multi-path from your browser. Also expand Long-lived port list with 80,443,8888,8080,8443 and try to play with  increasing circuit lifetime significantly